# notifications_on_conversation_id does not exist mailboxer rails issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, mailboxer

I upgraded mailboxer gem and followed the steps in the documents from 0.11 to 0.12:

```
$ rails generate mailboxer:namespacing_compatibility
    create  db/migrate/20140707050845_mailboxer_namespacing_compatibility.rb
$ rails generate mailboxer:install -s
    skip  config/initializers/mailboxer.rb
    Copied migration 20140707050855_add_conversation_optout.mailboxer_engine.rb from mailboxer_engine
```

Then when I tried

```
$ rake db:migrate
```

It gives me an error

```
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "notifications_on_conversation_id" does not exist
```

Any suggestions what this means? and how to fix?

Thanks

Comment: Well...i see error but dont see where exactly came from...so could be a sintaxis and also check if the real file problem

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem upgrading from mailboxer 0.9.0 to 0.12.4 (on rails 3.2.19).

what i did was to manually edit the migration created by the `namespacing_compatibility` generator as follows:

- in the up migration i prefixed the "from" index names with "index_" in the `rename_index` commands.
- in the down migration, i similarly renamed the "to" index names.
- also in the down migration, i found i needed to move the `update_all` command to the beginning, before the `rename_table` commands.

my edited migration ended up like this. here i have indicted the edited lines with comments.

```
class MailboxerNamespacingCompatibility < ActiveRecord::Migration

  def self.up
    rename_table :conversations, :mailboxer_conversations
    rename_table :notifications, :mailboxer_notifications
    rename_table :receipts,      :mailboxer_receipts

    if Rails.version < '4'
      # i edited the next two lines by adding the index_ prefix
      rename_index :mailboxer_notifications, :index_notifications_on_conversation_id, :mailboxer_notifications_on_conversation_id 
      rename_index :mailboxer_receipts,      :index_receipts_on_notification_id,      :mailboxer_receipts_on_notification_id 
    end

    Mailboxer::Notification.where(type: 'Message').update_all(type: 'Mailboxer::Message')
  end

  def self.down
    # i moved this line from the end of the down block to here
    Mailboxer::Notification.where(type: 'Mailboxer::Message').update_all(type: 'Message')

    rename_table :mailboxer_conversations, :conversations
    rename_table :mailboxer_notifications, :notifications
    rename_table :mailboxer_receipts,      :receipts

    if Rails.version < '4'
      # i edited the next two lines by adding the index_ prefix
      rename_index :notifications, :mailboxer_notifications_on_conversation_id, :index_notifications_on_conversation_id
      rename_index :receipts,      :mailboxer_receipts_on_notification_id,      :index_receipts_on_notification_id
    end
  end
end
```

i then ran the migration, ran the other (mailboxer:install) generator, and ran that migration. so far things seem to be working.